# How do I draw a bar under a node in tikz?

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-pic

I have the following tikz template (in the file `template.tex`), where I define a tikzpicture

```
\def\mysearchtree{
\begin{tikzpicture}[-, >=stealth', level/.style={sibling distance = 4cm/##1, level distance = 2cm}] 

\node [circle_node] (A) {$1$}
child { node [circle_node] (B) {$2$}    
    child { node [circle_node] (D) {$3$} }
    child { node [double_circle_node] (E) {$5$} }
}
child { node [circle_node] (C) {$3$}    
    child { node [circle_node] (F) {$1$} }
    child { node [circle_node] (G) {$4$} }
};


% Add labels to nodes
\node [blue, above] at (A.north) {$[1]$};
\node [blue, above left] at (B.north) {$[2]$};
\node [blue, above right] at (C.north) {$[3]$};
\node [blue, above left] at (D.north) {$[4]$};
\node [blue, above right] at (E.north) {$[5]$};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

In my main file, called `main.tex`, I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

% Define a few styles for the nodes
\tikzset{
  tree_node/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  circle_node/.style = {tree_node, circle, black, draw=black, text width=1.5em, very thick},
  double_circle_node/.style = {circle_node, double}
}

\begin{document}

\input{template}
\mysearchtree

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to have a bar under certain nodes, e.g. under node D. The reason is that this tree is supposed to represent the search tree of a BFS algorithm and, when we visit that node D, the corresponding node in the search tree, i.e. 3, cannot be expanded, as it's already been expanded. The way I need to represent this is with a bar under node D, not under the number 3. How can I do that?

Comment: Add `\draw (D.south west) -- (D.south east);` to the diagram?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think about the circle shape. `\draw (D.south) ++(-10pt,-2pt)  -- +(20pt,0);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remember the picture and add the bar via overlay.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\def\mysearchtree{
\begin{tikzpicture}[-, >=stealth', level/.style={sibling distance = 4cm/##1,
level distance = 2cm},remember picture] 

\node [circle_node] (A) {$1$}
child { node [circle_node] (B) {$2$}    
    child { node [circle_node] (D) {$3$} }
    child { node [double_circle_node] (E) {$5$} }
}
child { node [circle_node] (C) {$3$}    
    child { node [circle_node] (F) {$1$} }
    child { node [circle_node] (G) {$4$} }
};
% Add labels to nodes
\node [blue, above] at (A.north) {$[1]$};
\node [blue, above left] at (B.north) {$[2]$};
\node [blue, above right] at (C.north) {$[3]$};
\node [blue, above left] at (D.north) {$[4]$};
\node [blue, above right] at (E.north) {$[5]$};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{filecontents*}

% Define a few styles for the nodes
\tikzset{
  tree_node/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  circle_node/.style = {tree_node, circle, black, draw=black, text width=1.5em, very thick},
  double_circle_node/.style = {circle_node, double}
}

\begin{document}

\input{template}
\mysearchtree

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red] ([yshift=-2mm]D.south west) -- ([yshift=-2mm]D.south east);}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]